# APScheduler(Advance Python Scheduler) ImportError: No module named scheduler

Tags: python

I am having following import error

"ImportError: No module named scheduler"

when I run the following python script:

```
"""
Demonstrates how to use the blocking scheduler to schedule a job that execute$
"""

from datetime import datetime
import os

from apscheduler.scheduler import BlockingScheduler


def tick():
 print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())


if __name__ == '__main__':
 scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
 scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=3)
 print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'$

try:
    scheduler.start()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    pass
```

I have installed APS scheduler using: 
sudo pip install apscheduler

I have also upgraded using:
sudo pip install apscheduler --upgrade
Also upgraded my system using "sudo apt-get install update && sudo apt-get upgrade"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your import is wrong.  It should be:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
```

Reference example [here](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/master/examples/schedulers/blocking.py):

```
"""
Demonstrates how to use the blocking scheduler to schedule a job that executes on 3 second
intervals.
"""

from datetime import datetime
import os

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler


def tick():
    print('Tick! The time is: %s' % datetime.now())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=3)
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

Comment: the "here" url is  invalid

Comment: @SteveJiang:  Thanks.  Fixed.

Comment: Would this continue to run even when I exit or close/shutdown my pc?

Comment: @Sillians_Scilit Nothing will run if you shut down your PC.  If you're asking if the program will still run if your computer goes to sleep, then no it won't.

Comment: @Gerrat thanks for your comment, what scheduler or how can I use a scheduler for in  a python script for production. Please do recommend.

Comment: @Sillians_Scilit comments aren't the place for new questions.  Try posting a new question.

Answer (score 31):

I got same issue, but then I found,

I had installed apscheduler version 3
then I shifted to version 2.1.2 using,

```
pip uninstall apscheduler
pip install apscheduler==2.1.2
```

Just checkout before switching to version 2.1.2, If you wanted to use extra features added in version 3. In my case I didn't wanted much.

Comment: You may need `python3.7` if you prefere to use `apscheduler==3.x`. `python3.7 -m pip install apscheduler`