# python apscheduler - skipped: maximum number of running instances reached

Tags: python, cron, scheduler, apscheduler

I am executing a function every second using Python apscheduler (version 3.0.1)

**code**:

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(runsync, 'interval', seconds=1)
scheduler.start()
```

It's working fine most of the time but sometimes I get this warning:

```
WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job "runsync (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2015-12-01 11:50:42 UTC)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
```

1.Is this the correct way to execute this method?

2.What does this warning mean? Does it affect the execution of tasks inside the function in anyway?

3.how to handle this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It means that the task is taking longer than one second and by default only one concurrent execution is allowed for a given job. I cannot tell you how to handle this without knowing what the task is about.

Comment: Hi Alex, The Task check for a folder inside a FTP location and if the folder is found it starts fetching data from those folders which can take upto 24 hours.

Comment: Since this process takes longer than a second, you are going to be seeing those warnings a lot. You don't need to do anything about it though.

Answer (score 24):

## Increase `max_instances`

If the particular use case permits it, simply increase `max_instances` as shown below.

```py
import apscheduler.schedulers.background

scheduler = apscheduler.schedulers.background.BackgroundScheduler({'apscheduler.job_defaults.max_instances': 2})
```

There are three `apscheduler` configuring styles. These are described in the [documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#configuring-the-scheduler). Above is the dictionary/JSON style, here is the argument style:

```py
import apscheduler.schedulers.background

scheduler = apscheduler.schedulers.background.BackgroundScheduler(job_defaults={'max_instances': 2})
```

Answer (score 12):

If you want concurrently running instances of the same job and avoid the warning, you can include the `max_instances` argument in the scheduler's `add_job()` method. The default value is one.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure my task is not taking more than the interval. I just followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21214385/5153500) instead and switched to `apscheduler==2.1.2` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25710016/5153500).

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the maximum number of allowed running instances when adding the job using the `max_instances` parameter:

```
scheduler.add_job(runsync, 'interval', seconds=1, max_instances=2)
```